# Low banking moderately high level runescape monsters

Tags: runescape

My wife and I are semi-casual Runescapers. We were doing iron/steel dragons today, and she said while it was fun, the monsters took too long to kill. Note that she's only 77/77/77 for combat stats, so things do take a while. (I'm max melee, but that doesn't help her!)

What I like about steel dragons is that you're completely safe/protected, and that you don't have to bank very often. I'm looking for a monster that would be lower level than iron dragons, but still provide a **safe environment**, **decent drops**, and significant length of time **(30-60 minutes) between each banking**.

If this exists, where can I find this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the armor your wife is using, Greater Demons or Fire Giants can do that. If you normally kill with her, my choice would be for fire giants, I have not played runescape in around 2 years. However when I did play my wife was low combat level (im maxed, but 95 str) so we would go to fire giants and kill them, when she was low on food I would give her a few pieces and they also drop lobsters which help also. Most items they drop can be stacked and the rune items that get dropped you can either carry runes to high alchmey the items to make even more inventory space for longer trips.

Other think is I would work on my range there why she worked on her stats, so I would just carry a dozen or so sharks for her to use while I took no health. I dont remember her stats exactly but she was like mid 80s def, low 70s str, high 70/low 80 att and she would last this way for about 45 minutes a trip.

Comment: Oh I like that idea - I definitely need to work on my ranged... it hovers at 88, i rather hate training it. I guess with this I wouldn't really notice it. Fire giants seem like they'd drop better things, and that stackables/alchables seem right. My initial thought is that fire giants would be a little too low level, but now that I think about it I'm sure it's fine. Thanks!

Comment: @corsiKa The thing with monsters is it does not matter on thier level, it matters on the amount of health they have. Fire giants have higher health so you get more experience per kill... This could of changed in the past year or so, but this is how it was before.

Comment: Well, for experience, yes. But my wife is splashing a lot, which means the monsters' defense is too high compared to her attack. (Actually, monsters use the same combat level as players do, I believe, which both hit points and defense are a part of...)

Answer (score 1):

My favorite place to do this was the Black Dragons in Zanaris. It takes a raw chicken to get in, but it has a couple good ranging spots to use, and a good safe spot if you get in trouble. Plus, the dragon bones and hides are good money, or at least they were when I last played. Banking may be a little more often that you wanted, but there is a bank very close, so in my opinion, it's not really a problem.

Comment: It definitely is a good place, but they'd be at about the same difficulty as metal dragons, which she said were too long to kill for her taste. The ease of banking is nice though. We'll see :)

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't remember how difficult they were compared to metals. It's been a while since I've played.